# NMock Problem with Lists

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nmock

I have the following test using NMock which fails. It used to work when the result from the service call was passed to the view but it now fails since the results are converted to dto's.

I think this might mean I need to create a custom matcher but I am not sure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Error Message:

```
Test method Dgc.Cpo.RM.UI.Presentation.Test.ProjectPresenterTest.LoadProjectsTest threw exception:  NMock2.Internal.ExpectationException: unexpected invocation of projectView.SetProjects(<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dgc.Cpo.ResourceManagement.UI.Presentation.ProjectPresentationDto]>)
```

Expected:
  1 time: projectView.SetProjects(equal to ) [called 0 times]
.

Code:

```
public void LoadProjectsTest()
    {
        IList<ProjectServiceGetProjectsResponse> expectedGetProjectsResponse = new List<ProjectServiceGetProjectsResponse>();
        expectedGetProjectsResponse.Add(new ProjectServiceGetProjectsResponse() { Id = 1, Name = "Project 1", RefNo = "001", Complete = false, Dropped = false });
        expectedGetProjectsResponse.Add(new ProjectServiceGetProjectsResponse() { Id = 2, Name = "Project 2", RefNo = "002", Complete = true, Dropped = false });
        expectedGetProjectsResponse.Add(new ProjectServiceGetProjectsResponse() { Id = 3, Name = "Project 3", RefNo = "003", Complete = false, Dropped = true });

        IList<ProjectPresentationDto> expectedSetProjectsRequest = new List<ProjectPresentationDto>();
        expectedSetProjectsRequest.Add(new ProjectPresentationDto(expectedGetProjectsResponse[0]));
        expectedSetProjectsRequest.Add(new ProjectPresentationDto(expectedGetProjectsResponse[1]));
        expectedSetProjectsRequest.Add(new ProjectPresentationDto(expectedGetProjectsResponse[2]));

        ProjectPresenter_Accessor target = new ProjectPresenter_Accessor(this.mockView,
                                                                         this.mockProjectService);

        Expect.Once.On(this.mockProjectService).Method("GetProjects").Will(Return.Value(expectedGetProjectsResponse));
        Expect.Once.On(this.mockView).Method("SetProjects").With(expectedSetProjectsRequest);

        target.LoadProjects();

        this.mock.VerifyAllExpectationsHaveBeenMet();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it - you need to create a custom matcher and a static factory class, as described in the "Customer Matchers in NMock 2.0" section of the [NMock 2.0 advanced topics documentation](http://nmock.sourceforge.net/advanced.html).

By default, NMock uses `Equals` to match arguments passed to expectations (in your case, to see whether `LoadProjects` sets `mockView.Projects` to `expectedSetProjectsRequest` or not).

The `List<T>.Equals` implementation (inherited from `Object`) just [checks whether the two variables reference the same object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx), and in this case they clearly do not. (It looks like the `LoadProjects` method creating a new DTO list instance in the process of  transforming the get accessor results into DTOs.)

You have to tell NMock what to do instead of checking reference equality. Luckily the custom `ListMatcher` (and corresponding `IsList` class) from the NMock documentation I linked above may do the trick all by itself. If `ProjectPresentationDto.Equals` checks for value equality, you can use that example class as-is. If not, you'll have to customize it to define equality for your DTOs.

Comment: The above link NMock 2.0 advanced topics documentation (http://www.nmock.org/advanced.html) is broken. New link to the documentation is http://nmock.sourceforge.net/advanced.html. Thanks a ton for the answer